# Fastest way to asynchronously execute a method?

Tags: c#, performance, multithreading, asynchronous

i´m currently dealing with a problem where i have to dispatch hell a lot of functions to another thread to prevent the current function from blocking.
now i wonder what the fastest way is to perform this task.

currently i´m stuck with

```
ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem
```

as its slightly faster than the regular QueueUserWorkItem. however, i´m afraid that the threadpool may block this here. is there a faster way of dispatching a method call to another thread?
i just wonder what the best practice is for such a task? unsafe code would be no problem as it i´s in a scenario where already a lot of interop is used.
thanks
j.

Comment: When you say 'faster' do you mean that you want to reduce blocking on the 'main' thread?  Specifically, that the call that queues the item for background processing returns as quickly as possible?

Comment: WRT your stated concern, the threadpool doesn't block for that call (or the normal 'safe' one), but it does return a bool for whether it was queued successfully, with the theory being that if it returns false,  you might want to execute it on the current thread, or try again later, or whatever.

Comment: Are you dispatching to the same method each time?  Do they need to operate async from each other?  Is a producer/consumer approach acceptable? (so the caller just adds something to a queue).  Which version of .NET is this on?

Comment: yeah, i want the "dispatching" thread to return as fast as possible. if the actual executino of the dispatched method call is delayed for some msecs i don´t care. its jut about fast return times and till now, unsafequeueuserworkitem was the fastest. or is there another method of dispatching hundrest of small work-portions to another thread while returning very quickly in the calling thread?

Comment: i get lots of Request()-calls for a specific object (afew hundreds per second) and asynchrounously return these objects that take little longer to generate (can be parallelized) (distributed over say 20-30 instances of the same class). however, the method that calls these Request()-method needs them to return very fast as it would break down the whole processing otherwise. there is no way to alter the Request()-calling code.

Comment: Isn't QueueUserWorkItem non-blocking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLR(4) team recommends:

> Task is now the preferred way to queue work to the thread pool.

Read [CLR 4.0 ThreadPool Improvements: Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericeil/archive/2009/04/23/clr-4-0-threadpool-improvements-part-1.aspx)  and [New and Improved CLR 4 Thread Pool Engine](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/New-And-Improved-CLR-4-Thread-Pool-Engine.aspx) for detail information. In short, reasons are: **local queues, threads reusing, work stealing**. Basiclly for load balancing goal.

Extras:

I don't understand why it's not the answer (downvoted).

You wrote

> i have to dispatch hell a lot of functions to another thread to
>   prevent the current function from blocking"

I reply:
Some TPL (exists for net35) 'blocks' (**concurrent collections, spinning primitives** etc) are designed specifically for highly concurrent access, with the **focus on minimizing or eliminating blocking** for efficient management of work. You can use those blocks as well (for ex. - BlockingCollection for your problem). TPL designed for creating and handling hundreds (or even thousands) of cpu/io-bound operations (tasks) with minimal overhead (or millions with the help of PLinq).

You asked:

> i just wonder what the best practice is for such a task?

I've already answered: best practice - TPL (reasoned, not just my recommendation)

Comment: +Extras. Please add comments if downvoting

Answer (score 1):

Inserting multiple or bigger items at once should reduce the overhead.

Edited after reading one of your comments:

I have experienced similar things. My usual remedy is not to dispatch every asynchronous request immediately but rather mimic what [Nagle's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) does for TCP.

Here, upon receiving a Request() you would dispatch it immediately only if no asynchronous work is pending. If asynchronous work is pending you would dispatch only if a certain number of milliseconds since the earliest non-dispatched Request has elapsed or a certain number of outstanding Request()s has accumulated.

This is an effective  pattern to cut down overhead when getting frequent Request()s over which you have no control. Hope that helps.

Comment: Wouldn't this work against the premise of the OP that the intent is to dispatch very fast. The execution of the consumers doesn't matter to the producer. In such a case a Nagle's type of buffering might not be helpful isn't it ?

Comment: "dispatch very fast" is ambiguous. A Nagle algorithm ensures reasonably low dispatch latency and very good thoughput. That's what I call fast dispatch though let's hear the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could throw all your dispatch requests into a List<> and wake up another background thread to make the calls to QueueUserWorkItem.

Am I understanding the problem correctly?